# Can I "observe" a "sound" or only a "sight"?

Tags: word-usage

I am sitting quietly trying to see and hear sights and sounds. So I am "observing sights" but am I "observing sounds" or is there another word for "sound" perception?

Comment: Observe sound = note

Comment: Observations include what you hear, not just what you see.  If I were writing student observations and couldn't include what I heard them say and answers they orally gave, that would make those written observations pretty strange.

Answer (score -1):

Sound perception = to hear. That said, observe is not restricted to physically seeing.

"He observed the law and was a good citizen." is one example I can think of off the top of my head.

"The first Christians continued to observe the Jewish festivals." is another example I found online.

To answer your question, it is not incorrect to say "I am observing sights and sounds."

Observe has a diverse array of usages and meanings. In the future, check a dictionary or thesaurus and provide your research.